# How to represent basic Mixin behavior in C++

Tags: c++, mixins

Consider an existing C++ class hierarchy: one root class, many children classes forming a direct acyclic graph.

I would like to add a method to the root class, and possibly override it in some children. **But the problem is that it is forbidden for me to modify these existing classes** (3rd party library, project policy, closed source, etc..).

A mixin/extension class would then be a good solution. But it is not trivially feasible in C++.

The quick and dirty solution is to write a function that dispatches on the type of the object using 
the **dynamic_cast** operator, and performing the wanted code to each type of the hierarchy. But it is somewhat a bad practice, since
it is error prone to write, it breaks encapsulation, and does not support safely future changes.

I am thinking about maintaining some kind of hash-table somewhere with the definition **{rtti type id, function to call}**", and use that as
a *fake VTable* for the function I want to  write and override. But I'm not sure if it would be better...

Any other ideas? Runtime VTable alteration? Template meta-programming solution? Other?

Don't forget: I definitively can't change the original classes (neither headers nor implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot alter the original hierarchy, then template meta-programming is unlikely to help. Remember it's based on compile-time information.

Altering the vtable seems like an extremely bad idea, it's obviously non-portable and presume that you somewhat know its physical layout... even if you get it right it will be a maintenance nightmare.

I quite like the `std::map<type_info, Func>` idea. `std::type_info::before` offers you all is needed for implementation (don't rely on the name or address).

Comment: Ok, then I will use the std::map<type_info, Func> system. Thanks for the advince with ::before.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I'm writing a library that does just that: allows you to compose and modify types from existing classes at runtime, with the cost of not being able to call the methods as... er methods, but as external functions with first argument `this`. It's non-intrusive so you don't need to modify the existing classes in any way.

Code: https://github.com/iboB/boost.mixin

Doc: http://ibob.github.io/boost.mixin/

Hope it helps.

PS. It's called Boost.Mixin, because I intend to submit it to Boost, but it's NOT part of Boost yet.

Answer (score 1):

Write a free function.

```
void vfunc(base& param);

// ...
base b;
vfunc(b);

deriv0 d0;
vfunc(d0);
```

Comment: That what I done, and used dynamic_cast on the types to simulate method override. But I think it is not a good way to do things. What I am looking for is a cleaner way to do it (like with runtime Mixins, etc.)

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you need `dynamic_cast`? If you need polymorphism then that function signature above is all you need. If you need compile-time polymorphism then make it a template. If you want specific behaviour for each of the classes in the hierarchy and no other then overload the function.

Comment: Except that if I overload the function for "deriv0", but only have a pointer to "base" (which could be an instance of "deriv0", or "deriv1", etc.), the overloaded function will not be called since function call dispatches on compile-time types only.